# ImportError: cannot import name 'SkipWrapper' from 'gym.wrappers'

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, spyder, openai-gym

When I want to import SkipWrapper It occurs an error

```
from gym.wrappers import SkipWrapper  
ImportError: cannot import name 'SkipWrapper' from 'gym.wrappers'
```

I can't find any solution on the internet. I tried to downgrade gym to 0.9.5 but It also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this import

```
from gym.wrappers.frame_skipping import SkipWrapper
```

OR
Downgrade/upgrade the gym package. Source Code installed should contain the SkipWrapper class definition.
https://programtalk.com/vs2/?source=python/9609/gym/gym/wrappers/frame_skipping.py

Comment: Importing this doesn't work, downgrade/ upgrade neither. Is it possible to download whole gym from your link?

Comment: Seems like SkipWrapper is not available anynore, here are list of wrappers available https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/wrappers/__init__.py. You can instead copy the SkipWrapper code from the link I shared above and define that function in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

'Monitor' has been removed from 'gym.wrappers' in gym0.23.
Running in the gym0.21, it is successful.